# Set a limit to privileges lost as a result of meta downvoting

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, meta, privileges

So I posted an unpopular feature request here on the Meta.  I knew when posting it that it was unpopular; however, I thought of several good points, and since SE is all about making high-quality posts-- I wanted to bring those points up to try to present the issue from a different angle than it's been presented previously.

Judging by the trend, I am likely to lose up to 100 reputation eventually.  I do not mind losing most reputation points; however, I am afraid this would remove my ability to participate in the Meta site (which requires 5 reputation points)-- and thus I'd be permanently barred from the Meta site.  I suggest not being able to lose more than 1 privilege level per question.  In other words, even if your reputation points go below the threshold for the next privilege level, you would still retain the privileges you once had [less one privilege level].

Comment: Meta SE doesn't have a 5-rep requirement to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no need for this to be considered for implementation.

Even though voting is different on Meta, I think the presence of lots of downvotes on a post here is something that you should seek to avoid wherever possible.

It is fine to raise an issue that you think needs addressing, but there are strategies to do that which, if you are out of step with the community, can attract downvotes, and other ways that can help to minimize them.

For example:

- Try putting your toe in the water rather than diving in i.e. mention your issue in comments on relevant questions and answers, and see if your idea seems to be resonating with or being dismissed by other commenters.
- Try to make your question neutral i.e. ask it in a way that does not also seek to provide your desired outcome as an answer.  You can then wait for others to provide the for and against sides as answers, letting you just vote for what you want to happen.  If no one suggests what you are thinking, then you have the opportunity to not answer, or to take that risk and wear the downvotes if they come.  In the worst case at least your opinion is quarantined in an answer, which can always be deleted, whereas putting everything out into a question which gets answered and upvoted removes that opportunity from you.
- Don't post any feature requests soon after they first seem like a good idea.

My main advice would be to watch what the community is thinking, and try to veer it to where you would like it to go by suggesting incremental changes rather than proposing a revolution in one of your first questions.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I think this is a very good "Intro to how SE works" post; I'll heed this information.  However, what happens if I go below 5 rep?  How will I be able to come back?

Comment: @Alex that's a different question. Most users start at 1 so it must be possible. There's lots of questions here that offer advice on how to accrue reputation.